# mounting a network share with access for all users on the pi

Tags: mount

I've been googling this for the better part of the weekend and I'm stumped... I want to mount a shared folder (on a Synology NAS) on my RPi4. I've gotten this to work using various tutorials on this site and others. My fstab entry looks like this:

```
//<NAS-IP>/share /home/pi/share cifs username=<username>,password=<password>,uid=pi,gid=root,forceuid,forcegid 0 0
```

That works for the user pi... Now, there are other users (that are also in the group 'root') that need access to this share - they aren't getting it. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Best regards,
Andrew

Comment: Since your Synology NAS supports network file system (NFS) you'll have a much better chance of getting things to work in the way you want on a Linux system by switching from CIFS/Samba to NFS.

Comment: I think your `fstab` entry is wrong; read `man mount.cifs`. Also, the permissions (and usernames) applied in your Synology NAS must be consistent with those in your `fstab`

Comment: I switched to NFS as recommended by Dougie. It took some more googling and fiddling with settings on the server, but it works. Thanks!